# c++ vector of struct, why can't i use vector.at(i) or vector[i] for struct?

Tags: c++, vector, struct, compiler-errors

```
struct info{
  int num;
  int weight;
};
vector<info> nbr;
```

the above declarations are global, and I have a loop in my function that looked like this

```
for(int i=0;i<nbr.size();i++){
  info i = nbr.at(i);
  vector<int> v;
  v.push_back(i.weight);
  tb[i.num] = v;
}
```

`info i = nbr.at(i)` gives me error: no matching function for call to `'std::vector<info, std::allocator<info> >::at(info&)'`

why? what did I do wrong?

Comment: You should avoid redefining `i` as type `info` when it's your loop index.

Comment: You can't index a vector with an `info`. It makes no sense as is.

Comment: you are right, I redefined i, LOL

Comment: Voting to put on hold as the problem described is caused by a simple, typo-like mistake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for(int i=0;i<nbr.size();i++){
    info i = nbr.at(i);
```

This is why.
You're redefining what `i` refers to.
It's both your loop index `int i` and `info i`, and your compiler is wondering why you're passing an `info&` to `vector::at`.

Change the name and you should be good to go.